# The method validate(capture#2-of ? extends Object) in the type Validator<capture#2-of ? extends Object> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java, generics

I am sorry about putting the error directly as the title, but I couldn't find any better title.

I have an interface defined as following to be used as a blueprint for all my validator classes:

```
public interface Validator<T> {
    public boolean validate(T item);
}
```

And then I have some classes that would implement it, lets say one of them is this:

```
public class EmptyStringValidator implements Validator<String> {
    private final String _errorMessage;

    public EmptyStringValidator() {
            this("String cannot be empty.");
    }

    public EmptyStringValidator(String message) {
            this._errorMessage = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
            return this._errorMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validate(String item) {
            return gsi.application.core.Validation.isEmptyString(item);
    }

}
```

I would like to put it all in an array and call it all in one loop. So this is the code I am using:

```
public List<Validator<? extends Object>> validators;

public FormItem<T> addValidator(Validator<? extends Object> validator) {
    this.validators.add(validator);
    return this;
}

public boolean validate() {
    for (Validator<? extends Object> validator : this.validators)
        if (!validator.validate(this.getInputValue())) {
            this._errorMessage = validator.getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    return true;
}
```

However, that code is giving an error at the `validate()` function, specifically at this part:

```
validator.validate(this.getInputValue())
```

It gives me the error that I have mentioned

```
The method validate(capture#2-of ? extends Object) in the type Validator<capture#2-of ? extends Object> is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

which to my understanding doesn't makes sense. To my understanding `<? extends Object>` should accept anything that derives from the Object class, right?

Could anyone point out what am I doing wrong or point me at the right direction?
Thanks.

Comment: `? extends Object`  Makes no sense.True for all the classes.

Comment: That's what I thought, it should be true for every class that I put in, but it seems that it wont accept just any class.

Comment: What is the type of this.getInputValue()

Comment: `this.getInputValue()` returns a String

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an aside, `? extends Object` is no different from saying `?`. That isn't the root of your problem, however.

The issue is that `validators` is a `List<Validator<? extends Object>>`. In other words, each element can be *any* kind of `Validator<T>`, not necessarily a `Validator<String>`. So you can put a `Validator<String>` into it, but when you pull an element out you don't know what kind of `Validator` it is, and so you don't know if it is compatible with the type returned by `this.getInputValue()`.

The simplest fix would be to specify a concrete type (eg: `String`) for the type parameter. A more complicated fix would be to use a type variable in place of `? extends Object`, and have `getInputValue()`'s type signature use that same type variable. You need to constrain the types such that `getInputValue()`'s return type is assignable to the parameter of `validate()`.

Comment: I am sorry, you got me a bit lost. So in essence, what you are saying is that the return type and the parameter type of the function in `getInputValue()` and `validate` should be more relaxed, eg, using `? extends Object` rather than a specific type such as `String`. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: No. I'm saying that you probably want to do the opposite, actually. You probably want to declare `validators` as type `List<Validator<String>>` and `validator` should have type `Validator<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

An even better type for collected validators generally is `Validator<? super T>`, where `T` is the input type, in this case `String`.

This way `addValidator(Validator<? super String> validator)` accepts `Validator<String>` but also `Validator<CharSequence>` and `Validator<Object>`.

For example:

```
class LongerThan10 implements Validator<CharSequence> {
    @Override
    public boolean validate(CharSequence item) {
        return item.length() > 10;
    }
}

formItem.addValidator(str -> !str.isBlank())
formItem.addValidator(new LongerThan10());
```

In this specific case it makes not much sense, but it is a good idea to accept validators that work with super types generally.