# How to call a wildcarded method on a generic class?

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class where the type variable is used for the parameter of a method. How do I call this method when I retrieve instances of the generic class from a `Set`, `Map` or `List` using a bounded wildcard?

The super of the generic class:

```
//Verifier.java
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;

public interface Verifier<A extends Annotation> {
    // A verifier needs the annotation to extract verification information.
    public boolean verifyValue(Object value, A annotation);
}
```

A concrete implementation:

```
//MinMaxVerifyer.java
public class MinMaxVerifyer implements Verifier<MinMax> {
    @Override
    public boolean verifyValue(Object value, MinMax annotation) {
        if (!(value instanceof Number)) return false;

        long l = ((Number)value).longValue();
        long min = annotation.min();
        long max = annotation.max();

        return l >= min && l <= max;
    }
}
```

The annotation used in the example:

```
//MinMax.java
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Inherited
public @interface MinMax {
    long min() default Long.MIN_VALUE;
    long max() default Long.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

The class containing the offending call:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.*;

public class ParameterVerifier {
    private static final Map<String, Verifier<? extends Annotation>> verifyers
        = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        verifyers.put("MinMax", new MinMaxVerifyer());
        // verifyers.put(Range.class, new RangeVerifier());
        // verifyers.put(NotNull.class, new NotNullVerifier());
    }

    public void validate(Method method, Object value) {
        for (Annotation annotation : method.getAnnotations()) {
            String name = annotation.getClass().getSimpleName();
            Verifier<? extends Annotation> verifier = verifyers.get(name);

            if (verifier != null) {
                boolean valid = verifier.verifyValue(value, annotation);
                // ^ The method
                // verifyValue(Object, capture#5-of ? extends Annotation)
                // in the type Verifier<capture#5-of ? extends Annotation>
                // is not  applicable for the arguments (Object, Annotation)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get this working so users can add their own Annotation/Verifier pair, and the Verifier should be parametrized with the Annotation subclass. I don't care if I have to cast around a bit in `ParameterVerifier` (not in the verifiers, which are public API). I know how to make adding the pair type-safe with some extra logic, omitted here for clarity.

Related: [The method validate(capture#2-of ? extends Object) in the type Validator<capture#2-of ? extends Object> is not applicable for the arguments (String)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842233/the-method-validatecapture2-of-extends-object-in-the-type-validatorcapture) and [Java generic/wildcard type mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23082949/java-generic-wildcard-type-mismatch/23083129#comment42136377_23083129) both suggests to limit to a specific Verifier subtype or to remove the type variable from Verifier. I'm looking for a more elegant solution. (Consider MinMaxVerifyer.java immutable and only work on the others.)

Comment: I am not sure it is possible without moving the generic parameter to the methos. For example see: `minmaxVerifier.varifyValue(null, somethingNotMinMax);` this seems to be unsound.

Comment: "I know how to make adding the pair type-safe with some extra logic, omitted here for clarity."

Comment: I have seen that comment, only I doubt it is possible. You would need something like `interface Verifier<A super Annotation>` which is not valid Java syntax.

Comment: Though in this case I can relax the requirement of `MinMaxVerifyer` being fixed if adding method generic parameters will solve something.

Comment: Sure, that is why I mentioned moving the parameters to methods (well, with a typo), though those are very different from the class generic parameters. Could try to phrase different what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to achieve that the library user can create their own annotation/verifyer pair (like `MinMax[Verifier]` above), add them to the singleton `ParameterVerifier` class, and create setter methods that use those annotations and call the `ParameterVerifier.verify(...)` to verify the setted value against it's annotations. `verify` will get the `Method` object of the caller (working, but removed from examples in OP) and iterate over it's annotations. It will throw exceptions when the value violates a verifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I haven't found this before. I thought I'd try every combination of generics. This compiles and does the job perfectly.

- Remove the wildcard (but not the generic) from the retrieved elements, then cast and tell the compiler it's safe.

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.*;

public class ParameterVerifier {

    private static final Map<String, Verifier<? extends Annotation>> verifiers
        = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        verifiers.put(Range.class.getSimpleName(), new RangeVerifyer());
    }

    public void validate(Method method, Object value) {
        for (Annotation annotation : method.getAnnotations()) {
            String name = annotation.getClass().getSimpleName();
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Verifier<Annotation> verifier =
                (Verifier<Annotation>)verifiers.get(name);
            if (verifier != null) {
                boolean valid = verifier.verify(value, annotation);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppressing warnings is generally not a good idea, warnings serve a purpose: to warn you that code is faulty and can cause problems. The code might run now but there is a likelihood of unpredictable errors occurring down the the road.

Comment: "to warn you that code is faulty and can cause problems" That's not true. It Just tells you the compiler can't verify that the code is safe because it's not able to consider everything the user intends. In those cases, when the user can prove that the code is safe, a `@SuppressWarnings` is the right course of action. (from Effective Java, item 24) (google "effective java pdf")